# modify the dict on Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Here is the data format:

```
original_data = [{'year':2015, 'missing_number':25, 'station':3}, {'year':2015, 'missing_number':15, 'station':6}, {'year':2013,'missing_number':28, 'station':9}, {'year':2013,'missing_number':65, 'station':10} ]
```

I want my original_data to be like this:

```
new_data = {'2015': {3:25,6:15}, '2013': {9:28, 10:65}}
```

Would you mind helping me?

Answer (score 4):

Use a loop, adding items to a nested dictionaries:

```
new_data = {}
for d in original_data:
    new_data.setdefault(d['year'], {})[d['station']] = d['missing_number']
```

The `dict.setdefault()` adds the second argument as a default if the key (the first argument) is not yet present, then returns the value for the key. This lets you build up nested dictionaries grouped by the `d['year']` values.

Demo:

```
>>> original_data = [{'year':2015, 'missing_number':25, 'station':3}, {'year':2015, 'missing_number':15, 'station':6}, {'year':2013,'missing_number':28, 'station':9}, {'year':2013,'missing_number':65, 'station':10} ]
>>> new_data = {}
>>> for d in original_data:
...     new_data.setdefault(d['year'], {})[d['station']] = d['missing_number']
... 
>>> new_data
{2013: {9: 28, 10: 65}, 2015: {3: 25, 6: 15}}
```

You could also use a [`collections.defaultdict()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to take care of creating new nested dictionaries per key:

```
from collections import defaultdict

new_data = defaultdict(dict)
for d in original_data:
    new_data[d['year']][d['station']] = d['missing_number']
```

`defaultdict` is a subclass of `dict`; you can 'reset' the auto-value-creation behaviour by setting `defaultdict.default_factory` to `None`, after which it'll act just like a regular dictionary again:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> new_data = defaultdict(dict)
>>> for d in original_data:
...     new_data[d['year']][d['station']] = d['missing_number']
... 
>>> new_data
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {2013: {9: 28, 10: 65}, 2015: {3: 25, 6: 15}})
>>> new_data.default_factory = None
>>> new_data[2020]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 2020
```